# Node update entry from database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-update, sequelize.js

I want to update an application from the mysql database with the values I provide. However, one of those attributes (*helpString*) doesn't get updated. The update method looks like this:

```
Application
    .find({
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'name', 'helpString', 'class', 'description', 'category']
    })
    .then(function(application) {
        console.log("Application: " + JSON.stringify(application) + "\n")
        console.log("Body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "\n")
        application.updateAttributes(req.body)
    })
    .then(function() {
        res.status(200).send('updated')
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.warn(error)
        res.status(404).send('not found')
    })
```

In the console I get those values, which are supposed to work:

> Application: {"id":21, "name":"abcdef", "helpString":"", "class":"class1", "description":"", "category":"email"}
>
> Body: {"name":"abcdef", "helpString": "abc", "class":"class2", "category":"email", "description":""}

but the *helpString* attribute doesn't get updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should it be `application.updateAttributes(req.body)` ?

Comment: sorry, it is, I forgot to modify.

Comment: Ok looks like you may be missing an important factor, while you update the table it usually needs a where condition for this mostly with primary key. Now you are sending the entire request object in the function but how the function is working you need to check. Usually if you are using some ORM then it would require the key for that to be used in where condition or even if you write your own code you still will require that.

Comment: Well I'm using Sequelize for node and that should update it accordingly. _.find_ in the second line of code gets the application that has the id I provided and returns it as a promise.